# Is it a contradiction to do a hypothesis test on 1000 simulated datasets and never get a p value <0.05. Type 1 error question.

Tags: type-i-and-ii-errors

I am trying to calculate the type 1 error of a bootstrap hypothesis test procedure (won't go into the hypothesis test here).

I ran the test on 1000 simulated datasets (simulated under the null hypothesis of no effect). The smallest p value I got was 0.45, giving my procedure a type 1 error rate of <0.001.

Is this a contradiction? Shouldn't I find p<0.05 in about 5% of the datasets?

Comment: Please show the null distribution of the test statistic and give your sample value. It would be useful if you can explain something about the statistic itself so that it's possible to work out if your results make sense or if they might point to an error.

Comment: You can also show us the qq plot of your p-values (they should be uniformly distributed between 0 and 1).

Comment: Which software package/random number generator are you using?  Some, like the old rand() in C are terrible.

Comment: @Elvis that is often true, but not always. For example, in a one-sided test the $p$-value is only uniformly distributed when the true value is on the boundary of the range covered by $H_0$. All other true values that still satisfy $H_0$ will lead to a distribution of $p$-values that deviate from the uniform distribution.

Comment: @MaartenBuis If $H_0$ is a composite hypothesis, yes, you’re right. But I would rather consider that in this case, the distribution of the test statistics is not completely specified, and neither is the $p$-value distribution...  matter of point of view.

Comment: I think more information is needed before this question can be resolved.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b, I suspect the error is to do with the bootstrap not rendering the test stat distribution well, or perhaps as P.Windridge alludes, the "random" data. I simulated data under a spatial random field, used an R package (RFsimulate). I'm looking at a likelihood ratio statistic. I used a block bootstrap to come up with the test stat distribution. Assuming my data properly random, I now think the unlikely type-1-error rate might indicate that the block bootstrap isn't doing a good job on the test stat distribution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can be more precise: if your test is performing as expected then the probability of finding a 1,000 samples from a population where the null hypothesis is true with a $p$-value more than .05 is $.95^{1000} \approx 5.3 \cdot 10^{-23}$. That chance is not zero, but pretty small (that is an understatement...).

If this were happening in a project of mine, my first step would be to assume that I made an error in implementing this simulation.

Comment: Right.  Moreover Hoeffding's inequality says there's prob. at most $\exp(-2  (50 - 10)^2/1000) = 0.041$ to see less than 10 significant results..

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat It is a simulation study, so these tests are the same test performed in a 1,000 different samples.

Comment: @MaartenBuis I know, I just wanted to add that little bit of information. I'll clarify my comment.

Comment: Since you are simulating different samples, your p-values are independent and this answer is correct. Be careful though, when performing hypothesis test on the same data your p-values are likely not independent and this does not generalize.

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat what do you mean?  bootstrap simulating different samples from the same data?

Comment: @P.Windridge Ignore the idea of simulation for a second. I'm just saying that if you, for example, were to collect data on [jelly bean eating and acne](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/significant.png) and did a test on the effect of teal jelly beans on acne and the effect of green jelly beans on acne then these p-values are likely not independent. The point of my comment is just to point out that the answer given by Maarten does not generalize to every situation.

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat, yes I get the XKCD comic example but there seems little doubt (in the context of the question) that the samples are independent.  If so, the comment is kind of irrevelant.  Now, I don't know much about bootstrap methods but I was wondering whether the data being bootstrapped by the OP is somehow atypical.  If the $p$ values are being calculated according to some asymptotically correct distribution then I can envisage situation when this would lead to large $p$ values nearly all the time.  More information is needed.

Comment: @P.Windridge I'm not disagreeing that the simulations are independent, I'm just pointing out that the answer requires independence for some future user who may read this answer and want to apply similar logic to their situation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should find $p < 0.05$ in about 5% of the datasets. Two things to consider:

1. The P-value is a random variable, so it's entirely possible (if improbable) that you didn't get any significant P's just by chance.
2. More likely, you have a bug in your code.

Comment: +1 If the distribution of the test statistic is highly discrete (i.e. most samples under the null produce one of only a few distinct values), it might happen, but it's usually obvious if this is happening.

Comment: Along the lines of @Glen_b's comment, I have a small quibble with "you should find p<0.05 in about 5%". A test is defined as being an $\alpha$ test if its size $\text{sup}_{\theta \in \Theta_0} P_\theta(X \in \{x:T(x)>c\})=\alpha $, so any test with a size of less than $\alpha$ is a valid level $\alpha$ test. So, say, you never reject the null, the test is still valid at, say, $0.05$.